# Modify Google Charts API to look like Google Zeitgeist

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-visualization

If you look here: http://www.googlezeitgeist.com/en/top-searches/steve_jobs

These charts are awesome looking.

If you look here:  http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Noticeably less awesome looking.

Is it possible to use the same charts Zeitgeist is using or would it be possible to modify Google Charts API to get charts that look like Zeitgeist?

I can't imagine Google isn't using their own charting API...

Comment: IE8 gives me a JavaScript error for http://www.googlezeitgeist.com/en/top-searches/steve_jobs. Not so awesome.

Comment: Those charts are probably custom-made just for the zeitgeist.

Comment: @amadeus Why are you using IE8?  ;)

Comment: @Juhana  Agreed.  Could you imagine being a developer on the Google Charts API team, and then someone sends you a link to Zeitgiest...Awkward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Built something similar to the charts in the zeitgeist app from scratch using Easel.js - http://hsivaram.com/tech/2012/01/09/demo-data-visualization-inspired-by-google-zeitgeist-2011/

Comment: did you make that just to answer this question? Also, did you make your SO account just to answer this question? Man, that's an awesome demo, too. The code looks pretty clean- what would you say to Jonathan and I cleaning it up and pushing it as a jQuery plugin?

Comment: Jonathan: Thank you!
David: Please feel free to take the code, clean up and modify as you like. Making this into a JQ plugin would be quite awesome! Yes, I sort of made it after I saw this question while looking for a canned solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, those definitely are not made with their charting API, those look like they were made by a graphics designer.  If those charts and animations are able to made with Google Charts API, I would sure be interested in finding out how.

Comment: I still haven't seen a graphics designer that could design something like that, and actually build it.  I am pretty sure they are custom, but, I had my hopes up.  Maybe we can all lean on Google and they will open source it. :)